# How to locate files using Chef recipe? locate instead of find

Tags: chef-infra, locate

Is there a way to use Linux locate in Chef/ruby to find required files?

Preferred is elegant way.

I have shell_out example in my head. I know that I can do it with Ohai. Better suggestions? It's important to write each line to array as well. Any help on this?

```
locate = shell_out('locate -e gcc')

if locate.exitstatus == 0 && locate
Chef::Log.info("Locate results: #{locate.stdout}")
end
```

Comment: What's the underlying problem you want to solve? Finding out if gcc is installed and if so, where?

Comment: We have decided to use locate in our company to increase chef-client run. The purpose is to find required binaries which are not packages via Chef. Shortly, the path is needed. So in our example 'gcc' should be not a package and sitting anywhere on the file system.

Comment: What are you planning to do with this information? Generally you wouldn't need to know the path to gcc for anything.

Comment: The next step will be to remove OR to remove and install newest version as a package. This affects not only gcc, but the principal is the same. It is simple question how to find the files on the file system.